# Woher kommt "Bananenstecker"?

Tags: etymology

The *banana plug* seems to be a German invention ([German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananenstecker#Verwendung)), although [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector#History) gives an alternative American origin.

But neither article discussed the origin of the word. It may be that I could find the origin if my German were better, but the only etymology I can find in English is in [bright hub](https://www.brighthub.com/electronics/home-theater/articles/62574.aspx) where it says:

> **Why Are They Called Banana Plugs?**
>
> First of all, what’s with that funky name? Banana plugs are small cylindrical plugs that have a very distinctive bulged prong. This bulge houses a spring that, when inserted into a socket, presses outwards to ensure a solid and secure connection. The plug takes its name from the shape of this prong, which reminds many people of a straightened out banana.

But I think this is a wild guess, as they offer no sources and it does not make sense. When we say something is *banana shaped* we are referring to its curvature - a straightened banana simply means "straight" - like all pins on plugs!

So can someone with better German than me please help?

Comment: Huh? It does make sense. The spring is bend like a banana.

Answer (score 13):

A picture is worth a thousand words, so let's take a look

[image]Referenz: Jan Kandziora, [Bananenstecker2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bananenstecker2.jpg), [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)

As you can see, there **is** a banana shaped spring. "Banana shaped" doesn't refer to the pin, but the spring which is part of the pin and holds it in place.

Or as english Wikipedia says

> The pin has one or more lengthwise springs that bulge outwards slightly, giving the appearance of a banana.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector)

**EDIT**

From the comments: @DavidRobinson "I wonder if there any evidence to support this or any evidence as to who first called it a Bananenstecker. Or whether it was named first in German or in English."

I tried to look up the origin of the word Bananenstecker. Whether it's some kind of marketing, made up by the inventor or a nickname given by the users. Unfortunately i couldn't find any "hard" evidence. The [patent](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?FT=D&date=19290821&DB=&locale=&CC=DE&NR=481293C&KC=C&ND=5) is described as

> Stecker mit Klemmvorrichtung fuer den Anschlussdraht im Isolierkoerper

and i wasn't able to look up the whole patent description in order to see if Hirschmann called it "Bananenstecker" or "banana shaped" back then.

**But** looking up old books from the late 1920s you will find it frequently used [as early as 1925](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bananenstecker%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1929&lr=lang_de). 1 year after its invention.

[ETZ: Elektrotechnische Zeitschrift: Ausg. A., Band 46,Teil 1 (1925)](https://books.google.de/books?id=jNDmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22bananenstecker%22&dq=%22bananenstecker%22&hl=de&sa=X)

> Die Firma Hans Boas hat nunmehr eine Neukonstruktion auf den Markt gebracht (Abb. 10), die äußerlich dem Bananenstecker ähnelt, durch

[Wissenschaftliche Abhandlungen der Physikalisch-Technischen Reichsanstalt, Band 9 (1926)](https://books.google.de/books?id=W4fkAAAAMAAJ&q=%22bananenstecker%22&dq=%22bananenstecker%22&hl=de&sa=X)

> Die leitende Verbindung zwischen den beiden Plattensystemen je zweier aufeinander- gesetzter Kondensatoren erfolgt durch Doppel- Bananenstecker.

Books using the english "banana plug" or "banana connector" seem to be published a [few years later around 1930](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22banana%20plug%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1940&tbm=bks)

[The Wireless World and Radio Review, Band 26 (1930)](https://books.google.de/books?id=el9VAAAAYAAJ&q=%22banana%20plug%22&dq=%22banana%20plug%22&hl=de&sa=X)

> The more modern "banana" plug, which is of tubular form with, four slots which do not extend quite to the end

**Therefore i presume the german word "Bananenstecker" was first.**

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose they look a bit like bananas. I thought it meant the pin looked like a banana. I wonder if there any evidence to support this or any evidence as to who first called it a Bananenstecker. Or whether it was named first in German or in English.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Please note that modern 4mm plugs still are called "Bananenstecker" by engineers although they do not have the banana-shaped spring any more.

Comment: One of the rare cases of a usefull picture.

Comment: Please note that according to German law, the angle in which a banana is bent can only be within a certain range. If your *Bananenstecker* doesn't adhere to that law, it shouldn't be called that way. Also, if a banana doesn't adhere to the law, it's not a banana!

Comment: Calling that in its entirety straight thing a banana plug is indeed misleading. It should be called a zucchini plug or a cucumber plug.

Comment: Yes, @Philipp, this has been very controversial in the UK as well. I think it is primarily EU law, not German law, although the UK fought against it. The general belief is here that Spain put pressure on the EU to introduce a law that favoured the straighter bananas from big estates in  the former Spanish colonies in central America over the more curved ones from small-scale farmers in the former British colonies in the Caribbean.

Comment: Thank you, @mtwde for your thorough answer. So we can assume it is originally German, but we cannot be more definite at present.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Actually, I was just being facetious. I thought this was a joke about German bureaucracy. I had heard about such regulations but didn't think they really were a thing. But it seems that reality once again surpasses fiction in its absurdity.

Comment: How strange, @philipp, I Googled *straight bananas* and got straight to the Wikipedia article [Euromyth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euromyth). It does show, however, that there are some EU regulations and that they did try to introduce more in 2008. The bit about the Spanish may be pure supposition but the UK definitely fought against it as Caribbean bananas are definitely smaller and curvier on average than Central American ones. Of course, here in the UK we are all looking back with envy to a time when our biggest problem in EU relations was the shape of bananas.

Comment: @DavidRobinson   Regarding "they did try to introduce more" (i.e. EU-regulations on produce) one should always keep in mind that any regulations on the form and size of products and produce are introduced **as a result of industry and trade organisations' lobbying for such regulations**. Blaming the EU for them is just stupid (if based on lack of knowledge) or unfair (if based on actual knowledge of the facts). Blame the trade organisations, not the EU!

Comment: Yes, @christiangeiselmann, I pointed out that it was alleged that it was the Spanish who pressed for this rule. I have no evidence that this is true, but if it is then I assume that they were lobbied by traders with Central American connections. But I think the EU would also have some liability as I would say they have a responsibility to get evidence from a variety of sources and not just accept what industry asks for as they will quite reasonably lobby for what is best for them. If the EU had taken this advice the diesel-emissions scandal would not have occurred.

Answer (score 2):

The German Wikipedia article you linked to in your question says:

> Seinen Namen verdankt er der Bananenform des Blattfederelementes, mit dem der Stecker relativ fest, aber dennoch ohne Werkzeug lösbar, in der Buchse sitzt.

Translated to English:

> It derives its name from the banana shape of the spring element, which causes the plug to stay in the socket quite securely, yet removable without the use of tools.

So, it's not the prong itself that is said to be banana-shaped (straightened out or not), but the retractable *curved* epement in the prong.

*I realize this is basically the same as what was said in [mtwde's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/47856/5999). Still, I found it worth pointing out an explicit reason for the name is provided in the very article the OP had linked to in the question.*

Comment: The quote is interesting as such, but your conclusion is wrong. It is not *because* somebody claims it in a Wikipedia article that something is true. The only thing you can argue is true is that *somebody claims* that there is a relation between the form of the spring and the name of the thing. I am not one of those who cry for *evidence needed* all day long in Wikipedia articles, but in this case I would.

Comment: "It is not because somebody claims it in a Wikipedia article that something is true." - where in the world have I claimed that?

Comment: Thank you, @O.R.Mapper for the translation which helps, but since the springs look only a *bit* like bananas, we definitely need more evidence than an anonymous author on Wikipedia saying this is the reason for the name.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I did not intend to present the WP article as some real evidence of any kind. I just intended to point out a possible reason for the name from precisely the sources you apparently expected one in, as indicated by your statement "But neither article discussed the origin of the word".